# Facebook Post Lower left corner icon

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, ios5

I need to add a lower left corner in facebook post using an facebook app.
   I integrated facebook on my iphone application using AppID of app.

But facebook post is not showing lower left corner icon in post.

I added images also in:- Facebook Developer->App->MyApp->App Details->Primary Icons

I am in urgent need of this.

for Screenshots

Currently displaying
http://i.imgbox.com/adjg1iDX.png

Needed 
http://i.imgbox.com/abeBrNxw.png

I need a lower left corner in left side of "like".

Comment: Have you tried publishing another story recently? I can see icons for your app.

Comment: Yes dude i have posted so many posts. but icon is not appearing. i have tried all things.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then. If you've cleared your cache and all that stuff, I'd report it at developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: But i need immediate answer from facebook developer side. I am in urgent. This is need of my client. please help.

Comment: If you haven't used the AppId for anything but testing, the quickest solve will likely be to just create a new app and grep your codebase for references to the old AppId.

It's probably some weird inconsistency with the old AppId, since I can't reproduce it with any of my apps, new or old.

Comment: i have tried with new app also dude.

Comment: Ok, this is almost certainly an issue with the image assets you're uploading then.

Can you link me to one of the generated stories that doesn't have the icon, and also a link to the image assets. Are they JPG, PNG or what?

Comment: Posts are showing lower left corner icon on feed screen of facebook. But if i go profile screen, then lower left corner icon doesn't appear. Images are in PNG format.